# How to sum a series with the last term being the denominator of user input in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, sum, series

In the series: 1/3 + 3/5 + 5/7 + 7/9 + 9/11 +.........#/nth,
I am trying to make the nth the denominator of a series such as if the user inputted 5 it would compute 1/3 + 3/5, 5 being the last term which the user inputted. I was able to make the code compute the number of terms such as 5 would compute 5 terms 1/3 + 3/5 + 5/7+ 7/9 + 9/11 . 
here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class n01092281
{
//for loop that computes a sum of the series
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your nth term for the series.");
      double userInput = input.nextInt();   
      double sum = 0.0;
      for(int i = 2; i <= userInput*2; i+=2) {
        sum += ((double)(i-1)/(i+1));
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: for(int i=1;i<=userInput-2;i+=2) { sum+=(double)(i/i+2);}

However userInput is expected to be odd given your question

Comment: The sum of all integers is `-1/12`, true story.

Comment: @JoeC The title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your for loop conditions. You are looping it for `userInput*2` times. Subtract it by `2` and initialize `i` to `1` since your series starts with 1 as numerator.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class n01092281 {
    //for loop that computes a sum of the series
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your nth term for the series.");
        double userInput = input.nextInt();
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (double i = 1; i <= userInput - 2; i += 2) {
            sum += (i / (i + 2));
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```